# Propositional form of sentence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What will be propositional logic form of this sentence:

**If the budget is not cut, then prices remain stable if and only if taxes will be raised.**

My Approach:
suppose

$p$=the budget is not cut

$q$=prices remain stable

$r$=taxes will be raised.

So it should be $p\implies (q \Leftrightarrow  r)$.

but I am confused between $p\implies (q \Leftrightarrow  r)$. and $(p\implies q )\Leftrightarrow  r$.

so what would be correct answer?

Comment: I think the first one... See where is the comma.

Comment: The natural language sentence is ambiguous, both could be correct. However, the reading represented by your first formalisation seems to be the more plausible one, given the comma placement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural language, in this case, the English language, is inherently ambiguous, and hence its translation into non-ambiguous logic isn't always straight foward.

In this case, I believe your first translation is the most correct, $$p\rightarrow(q\iff r)$$ and I say that primarily because of the placement of the comma within the statement.  The first clause reads $p$, and depending on $p$, it follows that $q\iff r$.

If the comma were placed as follows:

> If the budget is not cut then prices remain stable,   if and only if taxes will be raised.

This second sentence is best represented by $$(p\rightarrow q) \iff r$$